# Not seeing a cloned github folder in jupyter

Tags: git, github, jupyter

Disclaimer: I'm new to git and github

I was working on some code on my work system which I'm pushed to my github repository. On my personal laptop, I cloned that same repository into some folder which is showing up in Finder

[image]

but is now showing up when I try to open up the code in jupyter.[image]

I'm not really sure what is happening but if you have any experience with this, I'd really appreciate the help.

EDIT:

[image]

Comment: from you command line, cd into the directory you have the project and type `ls`. What do you get as a result?

Comment: Added it in an editan Edit

Comment: Have you tried opening it with other text editors?